# What is the difference between iReport and Jaspersoft Studio?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jaspersoft-studio

Both are tools for visually designing reports and both come from the same vendor.

Why is Jaspersoft pushing two similar technologies?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the FAQ of http://www.jaspersoft.com:

> **Why is Jaspersoft Doing this?**
>
> For years our community of developers asked us to support the Eclipse
> platform due to its popularity and capabilities. This feedback made
> the decision to build an Eclipse-based report designer easy.
> Jaspersoft users will benefit from the rich capabilities of the
> Eclipse platform and Eclipse developers will benefit from a complete
> open source BI stack to build and deploy their reports. We also aim to
> create a report design environment that is both powerful and intuitive
> so that it appeals to both the advanced and the first-time report
> developer.

So I think this is simply a fork with the goal to provide the designer as an eclipse based application.

Plus they also provide the designer as a plugin version for Eclipse:

> **Which Eclipse releases does Jaspersoft Studio work with?**
>
> The plugin version of Jaspersoft Studio can be installed on Eclipse
> IDE 3.5 or later. The compatible Eclipse releases are Indigo, Helios
> and Galileo.

Anyway I could not download the Jaspersoft Studio to give it a try because the [download page](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio) does currently not exist.

Comment: http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspersoft-studio

Comment: As I know( Correct me if I am wrong) IReport not support for java 8 and Jasper studio supports java 8.